# Updating child (Popup or Lighbox) and parent window events for session timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, session, session-timeout

I want to implement the "sessionTimeout" functionality, so the even if the User has open a secondary window or a lightbox the user should get the SessionTimeout popup and according to user's response, both Parenta nd child window should get the SessionTimeout event notification:

I am using sessionTimeOut Plugin from "**https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout**" and implemented on the Main page (Parent window) from where both Lightbox and Popup opens, Its working fine on the "Main" page. But even if I am working on the Lightbox or Popup window, the main window session expires.

Can you please suggest what should I do so even if I am working on child window the sessionTimeout should not prompt and if not working for sometime the prompt should appear on child window and should close the child window and logoff the Parent window.

Please find the code mentioned below:

**Code for Session Expiry Msg:**

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.idletimeout.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.idletimer.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Your session is about to expire!">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>You will be logged off in <span id="dialog-countdown" style="font-weight: bold"></span>seconds.</p>
        <p>Do you want to continue your session?</p>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // setup the dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Yes, Keep Working': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
                'No, Logoff': function() {
                // fire whatever the configured onTimeout callback is.
                // using .call(this) keeps the default behavior of "this" being the warning
                // element (the dialog in this case) inside the callback.
                $.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call(this);
            }
        }
    });

    // cache a reference to the countdown element so we don't have to query the DOM for it on each ping.
    var $countdown = $("#dialog-countdown");

    // start the idle timer plugin
    $.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
        idleAfter: 600,
        pollingInterval: 2,
        serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
        onTimeout: function() {
            window.location = "/Home/Index/";
        },
        onIdle: function() {
            $(this).dialog("open");
        },
        onCountdown: function(counter) {
            $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Popup Window Code:**

```
function basicPopup(url) {
    var popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=800,width=1350,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
}
```

**Code for Lightbox:**

```
 //Lightbox Function
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth: 1000,
        maxHeight: 800,
        fitToView: false,
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none'
    });
});
```

Let me know if you need any other detail.

Please suggest

Comment: This works only when URL is home/index/? I think you need to attach it also to fancybox div `.various`.

Comment: Yes... If I open a Popup or Lighbox, I Do get the timeout alert but only one Home page.. not on the Lightbox/Popop page...

Comment: You mean to say the whole function "$("#dialog").dialog({" should go inside " $(".various").fancybox({" and "function basicPopup(url) {"???

Comment: I don't think so, the documentation isn't clear. I'll keep reading.

Comment: Find a way to trigger the function once fancy box or popup or active. Put it in a function and call it.